# PHP Variable use after assigning value

Tags: php, forms

I have a form and review that I am adding prices too. Right now the code is as follows and works fine

html

```
<select name="DriverShaft" class="select">
  <option value="" selected="selected">Select Shaft</option>
  <option value="LE- light weight graphite weakest flex : 5.00">LE- light weight graphite weakest flex</option>
  <option value="LW- Light weight graphite weak flex : 5.00">LW- Light weight graphite weak flex</option>
  ....
  <option value="DX- Heavy weight steel extra stiff : 15.00">DX- Heavy weight steel extra stiff</option>
  <option value="DS- Heavy weight steel stiff flex : 15.00">DS- Heavy weight steel stiff flex</option>
</select>
```

php on the review part to get the shaft name and price if selected

```
if (!empty($_REQUEST['DriverShaft'])) {
    list($shaft, $price) = explode(":", $_REQUEST['DriverShaft']);
    echo "<div class='reviewItem'><span class='reviewTitle'>Shaft:</span>{$shaft}</div>";
    echo "<div class='reviewItem'><span class='reviewTitle'>Price:</span>{$price}</div>";
} else echo "";
```

My questions is once i `list($shaft, $price) = explode(":", $_REQUEST['DriverShaft']);` can I call `$price` anywhere after to return that value? I ask since I want to make an array at the end and add up prices from options like:

```
$total = array($price, $anotherprice);
echo "sum(a) = " . array_sum($total) . "\n";
```

Comment: Have you tried it? The answer is yes. Unless I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: @matt ya I was just going to mess with it. Might have jumped the gun on the question.

Comment: Also, consider using $_POST or $_GET if you can to prevent unwanted input to be processed by accident

Comment: No response to my answer ?